# Do pharmacies' terminals spread infections?

Tags: infection, epidemiology

Everybody who's purchasing medicine in a pharmacy has to write a signature on a touchscreen payment terminal, either with his/her finger or by using the stylos attached to the terminal. This practice persists today, despite the covid-19 epidemic. Is there any data available regarding infection disease transmission via pharmacy terminals?

Comment: What makes terminals any different from all the other surfaces people touch?

Comment: @CareyGregory, two things: 1. you *have to* touch either the terminal or the stylos, and 2. it's in a prescription *pharmacy*, frequented mostly by sick people.

Comment: I know some research has been done on whether COVID-19 is transmissible by surfaces, but last I heard the answer isn't in yet. However, it is known that the virus can survive on dry surfaces for several days so it's a good bet it is. But I'll be very surprised if anyone tests those terminals specifically.

Comment: @CareyGregory it's highly likely surface contamination was the mode of transmission on the cruise ships